# How to enable projection transformation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

My QGIS project has two layers, one layer is retrieved by Google layer plugin which fetches the static Google map image whose CRS is +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +units=m +no_defs and another vector layer is a postgis layer whose CRS is +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs.

I digitalized some polygon features from Google Layers and added it to the vector layer. However, QGIS seems do not make the automatic CRS transformation. How can I change its projection?

Thanks

Comment: You added polygons to the PostGIS layer? Did it overlay correctly before editing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To reproject layers (in the project CRS) you have to enable "enable on the fly reprojection" in the project properties.

Raster reprojection works only since qgis 1.7

With your project open, press `ctrl+shift+'p'` to open the project properties dialog. Check the box that reads "Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply export your layer with different coordinate system: click on layer and just go to "save as" where you can choose CRS

Comment: this does not work generally. It is adviced to reprofect and transform your shp as described here: Reprojecting and Transforming (vector) Data https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html