# How to Get QGIS to calculate Area in Layer's Units?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, field-calculator, area

I have a Polygon Shapefile in a custom CRS which has feet as units. The Qgis Map is also set to the same CRS.

When I open the field Calculator, and enter `$area`, I see that the proper area is calculated:
[image]

But when I save it in the Attribute table, some other value gets saved:

[image]

The ratio between the values seems to suggest that it is doing some conversion from sqFeet to SqMeters.

I was under the impression that the Field calculator would [calculate areas in the units of Layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/147166/442), but here it seems to be doing something else.

Instead of manually converting, is there a way to get QGIS to calculate areas in Layer's Units?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After reading this comment: [How to read the area column in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50535/how-to-read-the-area-column-in-qgis#comment66745_50548)

I found that there is a setting in Project>>Properties which you need to set.
[image]

By default it is set to Sq Meters, and that is why Field Calculator was calculating area in Sq Meters, and not Sq feet as I expected. Once I set this property to Sq Feet, the calculation gave me the area in expected values.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem, but I find it interesting that QGIS doesn't update those field based on your polygon crs you have defined. I had to use `area($geometry)`. See this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147147/area-is-calculating-wrong-using-area-in-field-calculator-qgis-2-8-1-wien/313845#313845)