# Google Earth Imagery not coinciding with OpenStreetMap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I did some research and Google Earth uses same Projection as OSM, but they differ. Whats even stranger, is that the layer added with quickmatchsearch from google earth does coincide with the OSM data, but the raster screenshot from the google earth app does not.

I exported the OSM data to DXF and need a raster image to put as background, but I need one that coincides.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Google Earth uses same Projection as OSM? not sure that statement is correct.  https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/the-google-maps-bing-maps-spherical-mercator-projection/

Comment: Have you got *on the fly* projection set for your canvas https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10087/how-to-enable-projection-transformation-in-qgis by how much do they differ? Is it a few metres, a mile or on the other side of the Earth?

Comment: according  to https://epsg.io/3857 GoogleMaps Bing and OSM are using the same EPSG 3857 code

Comment: I have got the on the fly projection set to "automatic". Not sure about how much they differ, but you can note in the images uploaded that the shape is simply disorted/not the same. Its very clear by looking at the "left diagional edge" of the blue shape. The google earth diagonal is much steeper.

Comment: I still haven't figured out this yet, any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Edit: I figured out that I was exporting in WGS 84 and not Pseudo Mercator. 
But now I need to export the google image in WGS 84, but I couldnt do that nor saving as image nor from print composer, it always goes back to its pseude mercator default projection...

Comment: If you're exporting as KML or KMZ they are **always in WGS84/Geographic**, it's in the spec but it's not widely known. If you have your image as Google Mercator (EPSG:3857) and want it in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) you can warp it but QGIS should be able to project on the fly provided the spatial reference of the raster layer is set. If you want a copy of your image warped to WGS84 the warp function https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hx-lASR7WHk may help.