# Open Basemap in different Projection (Transverse Mercator) - QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, basemap, web-mercator, transverse-mercator

I have data in a transverse Mercator projection which is a different projection from my base map (Spherical Mercator / Web Mercator / pseudo-Mercator). I really would like to create a map in a TM projection (using open/free basemap) but I couldn't find any open basemap with Transverse Mercator projection.

How can I create a map in TM projection where I include a base map in QGIS? 
Is there any base map that provides a different projection than Web Mercator?

Note: I'm using QGIS. In Arcmap this is not an issue since they provide TM base maps. If you zoom in (greater than 1:6000000) it ok but smaller than that you'll find your basemap pixelized.

Comment: Enable on-the-fly coordinate transformation and set your canvas to Transverse Mercator.. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10087/how-to-enable-projection-transformation-in-qgis you might also find the ArcMap basemaps are not TM native but ArcMap has on-the-fly turned on by default or the service you are getting them from will happily serve the maps in *any* coordinate system provided a special transformation is not needed.

Comment: @Michael Stimson, In fact it seems that exist: Please take a look on [NZTM Basemap] (http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=acc1211c291a4e649ec25f262319aa7d#!) I already did that enable on-the-fly coordinate transformation with the OSM basemap but it will be really pixalized and stretched.

Answer (score -2):

Web Mercator is also a form of Transverse Mercator system, but since it is getting pixalated. OpenBaseMaps are usually served through TMS (Tile Map Service) and doesn't allow much flexibility. You should try WMS (Web Map Service) instead of TMS as they can handle projections better. You can find some WMS [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WMS).

Comment: Web Mercator is a Mercator porjection, not a transverse Mercator projection.